# Integration by parts to prove a function is constant a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, integration-by-parts

Let $(a,b)$ be an interval on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f \in L^1(a,b)$. Assume that $$
\int_a^b f(x)g'(x)\, dx =0
$$
for all $C^1$ functions $g$ with support compactly contained in $(a,b)$. Prove that there is a constant $c$ such that $f(x)=c$ for almost every $x \in (a,b)$.

My thought was to use integration by parts so as to have $$
\int_a^b g(x)df(x)=0
$$
but since $f(x)$ is only integrable, it does not seem to work.

Any help/hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a standard result in calculus of variations (it is a version of the so-called "fundamental lemma").

First of all, by density argument, if the relation holds for every $g\in C^1$ with compact support in $(a,b)$, then it holds also for every $g\in AC$ with $g(a) = g(b) = 0$.

Let $c := \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f$ be the integral mean of $f$, and consider the absolutely continuous function
$$
g(x) := \int_a^x [f(t) - c]\, dt,
\qquad x\in [a,b].
$$
Clearly $g(a) = 0$ and $g(b) = \int_a^b f - (b-a) c = 0$, so that $g$ can be used as a test function.

We have that
$$
\int_a^b (f-c) g' = \int_a^b f g' - c \int_a^b g' = 0.
$$
On the other hand
$$
\int_a^b (f-c) g' = \int_a^b (f-c)^2,
$$
so we can conclude that $f = c$ a.e. in $[a,b]$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Is it a standard technique to consider this construction of $g(x)$ when trying to prove a function is constant a.e.?

Comment: This kind of construction is used every time you need a function satisfying zero boundary conditions (i.e. $g(a) = g(b) = 0$).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If you happen to know that 
$$ \int_a^b f(x) h(x) dx = 0 , \ \ \forall h\in C_c((a,b)): \int_a^b h\; dx=1$$
implies that $f$ vanish
then you may reduce to this situation by considering the difference 
of two such $h$'s. One of them will give rise to the constant $c$.

Comment: I've never seen the result you quoted -- would you mind giving a reference where I could see the proof (or a hint how I could prove it)? Thanks!

Comment: You may find it in e.g. Serge Lang, Real and Functional Analysis, section VI, Thm 9.3, but it appears in many books on integration theory. You may prove it e.g. by using that $C_c$ is dense in $L^1$.